# Cannot Delete S3 Bucket even though the IAM user as S3FullAccess policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I cannot delete the bucket from an IAM user account which uses a virtual MFA device profile

*I have generated session toekns and added it to the `profile` section of `~/.aws/credentials` file. and the profile config is added to the `~/.aws/config` file*

```
❯ cat config
[default]
output = json
region = us-east-1
[mfa]
output = json
region = us-east-1
```

and

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[mfa]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
aws_session_token = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

When I run the command to delete this bucket (it is empty)

```
❯ aws s3 rm s3://iac-bucket --recursive --region us-east-1 --endpoint-url https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com --profile mfa
fatal error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied
```

Also, the bucket does not show up in Management Console nor on `ls` command

```
❯ aws s3 mb s3://iac-bucket --profile mfa
```

gives no output, and

```
❯ aws s3 ls s3://iac-bucket --profile mfa --region us-east-1 --endpoint-url https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied
```

I have the following policies attached to this user via a group

[image: AWS Policies attached via Group]

How do I delete this bucket?
Why doesn't it show up at all? I know it exists because

```
❯ aws s3 mb s3://iac-bucket --profile mfa --region us-east-1 --endpoint-url https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
make_bucket failed: s3://iac-bucket An error occurred (BucketAlreadyExists) when calling the CreateBucket operation: The requested bucket name is not available. The bucket namespace is shared by all users of the system. Please select a different name and try again.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Bucket names must be unique within a partition. A partition is a grouping of Regions. AWS currently has three partitions: aws (Standard Regions), aws-cn (China Regions), and aws-us-gov (AWS GovCloud [US] Regions).

From the [Rules for bucket naming](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html#bucketnamingrules). Most likely a bucket with that name was created by a different account not under your control. That is why it doesn't show up. AFAIK there is no other way to resolve that than choosing a different name for your bucket.